# NgFor loop for nested array

Tags: angular

```
let activeOptions = [['Akteure der Erfasung',true,['hello','achi','ami']],['Orte der Erfassung',true,['a']],['Zeitpunkte der Erfassung',true,['b']],
  ['Rechtsgrundlagen',true,['c']]] 
           
<mat-option disabled = {{a[1]}} *ngFor="let a of activeOptions" [value]="a[0]" >
              <b>{{a[0]}}</b>
              <span *ngFor="let b of a[2]">{{b}}</span>
            </mat-option>
```

My 2nd NgFor is not working. Is there anything wrong? I know the nested object solution but I want to do it by the multidimensional array.

Comment: there are no problems with this code, the problem could be somewhere else, maybe where you are assigning activeOptions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that they array is not a single type, you have a string, a boolean and a string[].

So even though in your ngFor you are forcing the 3rd element, and you are sure that the type is array for that element, the compiler doesn't know. That is because your array already has 3 different types, and the ngFor is looking for an iterable type, which in this case cannot be warrantied.

One way to have a work around at this problem, is to assign the variable in your component like:

```
activeOptions = [
    ['Akteure der Erfasung', true, ['hello', 'achi', 'ami']],
    ['Orte der Erfassung', true, ['a']],
    ['Zeitpunkte der Erfassung', true, ['b']],
    ['Rechtsgrundlagen', true, ['c']],
  ];

  secondArray: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.secondArray = this.activeOptions.map(
      (activeOption) => activeOption[2]
    ) as string[];
  }
```

And your html like:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-option
    disabled="{{ a[1] }}"
    *ngFor="let a of activeOptions"
    [value]="a[0]"
  >
    <b>{{ a[0] }}</b>
    <span *ngFor="let b of secondArray">{{ b }}</span>
  </mat-option>
  <mat-select></mat-select
></mat-select>
```

Please find this stackblitz with the example for your reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agxpwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.css

Comment: Another way would be to declare the type of activeOptions to be `[string, boolean, string[]][]`. Or use `as const` at the end of the assignment.